# Placeholder is not shown in Text fields type password of custom M3 material

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose

I am customizing a text input via BasicTextField().
I see a strange behavior in the password type input, when it is empty it does not show the placeHolder, however the email type does show the placeHolder.

Below I attach an image where we can see the email text field that does show the placeholder even if it is focused or you have clicked on the element.

I would like the password text field to show the placeholder even if it has focus, I share the code that I have advanced so far.

[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SmallTextFieldPassword(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val enabled = true
    val singleLine = true
    val colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        focusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
    )
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var keyBoardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password)

    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { onValueChange(it) },
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(40.dp),
        // internal implementation of the BasicTextField will dispatch focus events
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        enabled = enabled,
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
        keyboardOptions = keyBoardOptions,
        visualTransformation = if (expanded) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        singleLine = singleLine,
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(Color.Black)
    ) { innerTextField ->
        OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
            value = value,
            innerTextField = {
                /*Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color(0xFFC4C4C4))
                ) {
                    if (value.isEmpty()) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Tu Pass",
                            color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = 0.6f)
                        )
                    }
                }*/
                innerTextField()
            },
            enabled = enabled,
            // same interaction source as the one passed to BasicTextField to read focus state
            // for text field styling
            singleLine = singleLine,
            label = { Text(text = "") },
            trailingIcon = {
                var image = if (expanded) Icons.Filled.KeyOff
                else Icons.Filled.Key

                var description =
                    if (expanded) "Hide password" else "Show password"

                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = !expanded
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = image, contentDescription = description)
                }
            },
            visualTransformation = if (expanded) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            placeholder = {
                Text(
                    text = "Tu Password",
                    color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = 0.6f)
                )
            },
            colors = colors,
            contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.contentPaddingWithoutLabel(
                start = 16.dp,
                end = 8.dp,
                top = 0.dp,
                bottom = 0.dp
            ),
            // update border thickness and shape
            container = {
                OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.ContainerBox(
                    enabled = enabled,
                    isError = false,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp) //OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.shape
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: The reason for this is that you're applying `VisualTransformation` to the `TextField` which is shadowing the placeholder text.